# Dynamic js-obj lookup

Tags: clojurescript

Given the following scenario:

```
(def object (js-obj "a" 1 "b" 2))
(def key "a")
```

How can one get the `1` value using only the `object` and `key` vars? This is, not just hardcoding `(.-a object)`.

The equivalent JavaScript syntax would be`object[key]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aget` and `aset` (array get and array set) functions can be used: `(aget object key)`